# check duplicate data in mysql in same cell

Tags: mysql

I have column call: customer_mobile. but inside that cell they have data like

'0875555555,0875555555,0875555555,0875555555,0875555555' .

I want query if data duplicate will show 1

Comment: what do you mean with duplicate? You want to see if there are more than one number inside the cell?

Comment: you should consider to normalize your db. This is a really poor database structure for what I can see

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in mysql google mysql unstrng or mysql split string for ways to explode strings.

Comment: @P.Salmon . I Already got it Thank bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can find specific string in comma separated strings like this

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('0875555555', (SELECT customer_mobile FROM your_table_name)) as found
```

It will return position like 1,2,3,4 if found otherwise it will return 0